# Master Page v4.master

Tags: master-page

I have changed my `v4.master` in my SharePoint site now I receive the message:

```
Unknown server tag 'Publishing Site Action:Site Action Menu'
```

And I can't see anymore my site.

How can I replace that `v4.master` with the original one ? (I have the file)

Comment: Rule number 1, Never edit a orginal Masterpage, always make a copy. You should be able to use SPD designer to reset the master page to the default definition.

Comment: Like @JulianoG said, you should use Sharepoint Designer and there you can browse to your v4.master and reset it to site definition. :) Here is a link that might include some information about the problem: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/reset-a-customized-page-to-the-site-definition-HA010174145.aspx#BM3

Answer (score 0):

How can I replace that v4.master with the original one ?

- Open SharePoint Designer.
- Connect to your Site.
- From Left side > Go to Master Page.
- Right Click on `v4.master` > Select `Reset to site definition`

[image]